# Bootstrap glyphicons does not show

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I build my angular app with [bulp angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) and the component

> Sass (Node)

I change the theme to flatly, downloaded it from [bootswatch website](http://bootswatch.com/flatly/) inserted into _bootstrap.scss

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootswatch/variables";
......  
.....
// Utility classes
@import "bootstrap/utilities";
@import "bootstrap/responsive-utilities";

@import "bootswatch/bootswatch";
```

the theme was taken as expected but the glyphicon does not show as you can see.

[image]

And html code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Gulp Angular
      </a>
    </div>
```

As you can see, I am using glyphicon in the right way.
Bootstrap version is

```
{
  "name": "bootstrap-sass",
  "version": "3.3.3",
```

Bootstrap file structure

[image]

What am I doing wrong? When I change to use LESS instead SASS then everything works fine.

Comment: Check what URL is being used for the fonts in the CSS and compare it against where the fonts actually are. See also http://getbootstrap.com/components/#callout-glyphicons-location

Comment: check weather you have font files in bootstrap-sass-official>assets>fonts>bootstrap and import that path in sass file. $icon-font-path: file_path;

Comment: Did you find an answer for your question?

Answer (score -1):

`$icon-font-path: "../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";`

Just before 
`@import "bootswatch/bootswatch";` helped me